# Maching values in dataweave mule4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

i am trying to match the values in below payload.

```
    result = {
        "drives": [{
            "id": "0AC_FdkeL63mHUk9PVA",
            "name": "QA"
        }, {
            "id": "0AC_Ype39GAOpUk9PVA",
            "name": "Salesforce.com"
        }, {
            "id": "0AA9MLlEbuhRfUk9PVA",
            "name": "UAT-zz-SFJobs-2020-10"
        }]
    }
```

Am using below code to check whether the value Salesforce.com is present there and return it.
using below code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.result.drives filter ((item, index) -> item.name == "Salesforce.com")
```

It giving me error how can i achieve this

Expected output:

```
"drives": [{
            "id": "0AC_Ype39GAOpUk9PVA",
            "name": "Salesforce.com"
        } ]
```

Comment: Hi, Daniel! Could you please give more details on the error you are getting? Thank you.

Comment: Your input appears to be a mix of Java and JSON. Likely error you are getting is because its try to read as JSON but its not properly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me. You need to create a `drives` attribute for the response to match the expected output.

Note that the input is not a valid JSON. That might be the cause of the error.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
    drives: payload.result.drives filter ((item, index) -> item.name == "Salesforce.com") 
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "drives": [
    {
      "id": "0AC_Ype39GAOpUk9PVA",
      "name": "Salesforce.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Input (adjusted):

```
{ 
    "result" : {
        "drives": [{
            "id": "0AC_FdkeL63mHUk9PVA",
            "name": "QA"
        }, {
            "id": "0AC_Ype39GAOpUk9PVA",
            "name": "Salesforce.com"
        }, {
            "id": "0AA9MLlEbuhRfUk9PVA",
            "name": "UAT-zz-SFJobs-2020-10"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this: Whenever you face an array of objects, you can filter based on the value of specific key. Here name is the key and equals to "Salesforce.com". So, objects with other names will be filtered out.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var result = {
        "drives": [{
            "id": "0AC_FdkeL63mHUk9PVA",
            "name": "QA"
        }, {
            "id": "0AC_Ype39GAOpUk9PVA",
            "name": "Salesforce.com"
        }, {
            "id": "0AA9MLlEbuhRfUk9PVA",
            "name": "UAT-zz-SFJobs-2020-10"
        }]
    }
---
{
    drives: result.drives filter ((item, index) -> item.name == "Salesforce.com")
}
```